# React - effect hook causing data loss with stream data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am creating a radio application that is storing a limited set of data from a WS stream. The data is used to render a time graph based on the data points received. I am rendering the data on a canvas, and it has displayed spectacular performance ability even at 60 data points received per second.

I am using an effect that stores the data locally at the graph component level, to avoid unnecessary re-renders; this effect runs at the same rate that the data is received (60 calls a second). However, I am experiencing that occasionally the effect fails to run and therefore a data point is dropped. This is causing weird artifacts on my D3 graph due to the interpolator missing a required data point.

Is there any way I can optimize or prioritize the receipt of this stream data? It is very important that all received data can be recorded, especially for other graphs that will be built into the page.

```
// App.tsx

// (in App component)

const handleWsMessage = (message: MessageEvent) => {
  const data: WSGenericResponse = JSON.parse(message.data);
  ...
  if (data.type === "sample") {
    setStreamMessage({
      receivedAt: utcTimeMs(),
      payload: {
        time: +data.time,
        value: +data.sample
      }
    });
  }
} 
...
return (
  ...
  <StreamContext.Provider value={streamMessage}>
    <LabeledTimeGraph radio={activeRadio} />
  </StreamContext.Provider>
  ...
)
```

```
// graphs/time.tsx

// (in TimeGraph component)

const sample = useContext(StreamContext).payload;
const TICK_COUNT = 4;  // defines how many ticks should be visible at once on the x-axis

useEffect(() => {
  ...
  if (data.length == 0) {
     setData([sample]);
  } else {
    if (data.length > (TICK_COUNT * radio.streamRate)) {
      setData(data => [...data.slice(1), sample]);  // clear old data
    } else {
      setData(data => [...data, sample]);
    }
  }
}, [sample]);
```